# How to unlock @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) if there is no transaction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, pessimistic-locking

I have put `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` on a query and working on it in service layer with `@Transactionsal` annotation. The lock is acquired successfully. But for some cases, the transaction could not be happened. And this lock takes time to be released. My concern is how can I release the lock immediately ?

Comment: What do you mean by "transaction could not be happened"?

Comment: I tried to make a http call to another service, but it returned timout. So it goes to Catch section without making any transaction (Like update). Then I need to release that lock immeadiately

Comment: I would say you should not lock anything if you have no tx in the first place.

Comment: You rollback the transaction; this will unlock all locks it holds in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly unlock by

entityManager.lock(entityObject, LockModeType.NONE);

Comment: That would be implementation specific as the JPA spec says nothing about unlocking locks - there are other lock types, and all this does in the spec is get (or check) a lock in the database. Optimistic locking for instances verifies and increments the version - only a rollback 'unlocks' or undoes the version change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).